# Why is the counter value not incrementing?

Tags: c++, string, char, counter

The counter does not increase at all so I want to know which part went wrong.

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


            
int main(){
   int total=0,na=0,ni=0;//use to count how much type of element is there
   string chem;
   getline(cin,chem);

   for(int i=0;i!='\0';i++){
       if(chem[i]=='N'){
           if(chem[i+1]=='i'){
               ni++;
           }else{
              na++;
              cout<<na<<endl;
        }
    }
}
```

*na and total values are both 0*

```
cout<<na<<endl;
total=total + ni+na;
cout<<total;
```

Comment: `i!='\0'` will be immediatly false, and you won't even do one iteration of the loop.

Comment: I think your loop doesn't even do an iteration. Check your for expression.

Comment: Use a debugger. And refer to [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems).

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i != '\0'; i++)` initialises `i` to zero, then only iterates if `i` is non-zero.  Which means it doesn't iterate at all.

Comment: Because this is just like `for(int i=0;i!=0;i++){}`

Comment: Presumably you meant this `for(int i=0;chem[i]!='\0';i++){`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(int i=0;i!='\0';i++){
```

is the same as

```
for(int i=0; i; i++){
```

(`'\0'` is a `char` type with value 0).

The conditional check means the loop body never runs.